# How can I get/check the contents of a cart via javascript (cookie)?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Within my application, I would like to only show a link to the the user's cart only if there are products in it.

I was going to use javascript to check the cookie I can see getting set. `commerce_cookie`

The problem I'm having is how to read that cookie. I realize its encrypted & I'm not accessing the cookie correctly. That's why I'm unable to get and check for any orders. Is there a better way to check the cart dynamically in this way?

I am trying to read it like this:

```
var cart = getCookie('commerce_cookie');

console.log(cart);  // false

// check if there are any products in the cart
if (cart) {
   // show the cart icon
} else {
    // hide the cart icon
}

function getCookie(cookie) {
    if ($.cookie(name)) {
        returnJSON.parse($.cookie(name));
    }
}
```

I have read through [this thread](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies/) about LJ Cookies, but I'm still not confident I'm looking for the cookie correctly:

```
{{ craft.lj_cookies.get( 'commerce_cookie' ) }}
```

**SOLUTION**

What I was tying to do was hide the cart icon and only show it (along with item quantity) *only* if there were items in the cart.

To do this, you'll need a plugin to listen for the `onBeforeAddToCart` event.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
// Listen for items getting added to the cart.
craft()->on('commerce_cart.onBeforeAddToCart', function (Event $event) {
    $cart = craft()->commerce_cart->getCart();
    // set expire & other params as needed
    $cookie = new HttpCookie('totalQty', $cart->totalQty);
    craft()->request->getCookies()->add($cookie->name, $cookie);
});
```

Then I've got an ajax request that will check if that cookie exists.

**jquery**

```
var data = {
    'CSRF': $('input[name="CSRF"]').val()
};

$.ajax({
    'type': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'cache': false,
    'data': data,
    'url': '/actions/myplugin/checkCookie',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'timeout': 50000
}).done(function (response) {
    // handle response
}).fail(function (error) {
   // Total fail.
});
```

That routes to a controller method within my plugin:

**MyPlugin.php**

```
if (craft()->request->isAjaxRequest()) {
    return $this->returnJson(craft()->request->getCookie('totalQty'));
}
```

Here is how I am then handling/updating the UI with the results of that ajax request. I am summarizing my code here, there is more logic than I am listing - just trying to keep the size of this thread below the level of "book".

I am using velocity for my transitions.

**jquery**

```
 ...
 var qty = (result.value + 1);  // value is zero-based array so +1

  $('#icon').velocity('fadeIn', {
      'duration': 300,
      'display': 'inline-block',
      'complete': function () {
          $('<div/>', {
              'id': 'cartQty',
              'text': qty
          }).appendTo($('#icon'))
              .velocity('transition.bounceIn', {
                  'duration': 300,
                  'easing': 'easeInOutSine'
              });
          }
      });
```

I wasn't able to find an event that listened for the Empty Cart event, so I had to get creative here.

I listen for the "Empty Cart" form submit via jQuery. From there I make another ajax request to my plugin:

**jQuery**

```
$('#emptyCartForm').submit(function (event) {
     deleteCookie(); // calls an ajax method (below)
});


$.ajax({
    'type': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'cache': false,
    'data': data,
    'url': '/actions/myplugin/deleteCookie',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'timeout': 50000
}).done(function (response) {
    // handle response
}).fail(function (error) {
   // Total fail.
});
```

That request makes a call to a controller method within my plugin:

**MyPlugin.php**

```
 if (craft()->request->isAjaxRequest()) {
     craft()->request->deleteCookie('totalQty');
     return $this->returnJson(['status' => 'success']);
}
```

I'm happy to edit or please feel free to edit if there is any way I can improve this technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie that Craft Commerce uses for cart/session management is set using Craft's `craft()->userSession->saveCookie`, which hard-codes cookie's `httpOnly` flag, meaning it can't be accessed by JavaScript.

If you want to pull of what you're trying to do, you'll need to use something like the [LJ Cookies](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies/) or [Cookies](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/cookies) plugin to add and ready your own cookie according to your business logic.

Comment: Thanks Brad! I've updated my question with what I came up with in case someone stumbles across this question.