# How can I delete a cookie from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, cookies

I am able to set a plain old cookie like this:

```
$cookie = new HttpCookie('myCookie', 'myValue');
```

I am trying to delete it like this:

```
$cookie = new HttpCookie('myCookie', '');
craft()->request->getCookies()->add($cookie->name, $cookie);
```

When I make a call to check the cookie, I get this returned:

```
{"name":"myCookie","value":"","domain":"","expire":0,"path":"\/","secure":false,"httpOnly":true}
```

I can see that the value is getting cleared, but is there any way to just totally wipe out the cooke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [deleteCookie()](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/HttpRequestService.php#L893) in HttpRequestService?

Comment: Thanks khalwat, that pointed me in the right direction. I've also [updated my other question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13478/how-can-i-get-check-the-contents-of-a-cart-via-javascript-cookie/) that is related to this for anyone who comes across this question.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find an answer for removing a cookie in Craft 3 so after plenty of time of trying to figuring it out, this is my conclusion.

First of all, I am setting the cookie using the following method.

```
$cookie = new Cookie(['name' => 'cookieName']);
$cookie->value = $data['accessToken'];
$cookie->expire = $data['expires'];
Craft::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
```

I kept running into a problem with the Cookies being set are read-only so in order to remove the cookie need to use response to change and remove cookies.

```
Craft::$app->response->cookies->remove('cookieName');
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie worked perfectly